# Trying to install MongoDBBundle For Symfony. using composer but it can not be resolved

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, composer-php

```
Anthonys-MacBook-Air:activebook numerical25$ php composer.phar update
PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA6 requires doctrine/mongodb >=1.0.0-beta1,<1.1-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA7 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA8 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA9 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.x-dev requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3].
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.3 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.5-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo has the wrong version (1.5.0dev) installed.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo has the wrong version (1.5.0dev) installed.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo has the wrong version (1.5.0dev) installed.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo has the wrong version (1.5.0dev) installed.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA5 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0-BETA1 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA4 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0-BETA1 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.*@dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.0.0-BETA4, 1.0.0-BETA5, 1.0.0-BETA6, 1.0.0-BETA7, 1.0.0-BETA8, 1.0.0-BETA9, 1.0.x-dev].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I dont know what this means

This is what I have in my symfony composer.json file

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@dev",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev"
},
```

Comment: and what is the "minimum-stability" value ?

Comment: having kinda the same issue, thoughts: doctrine/mongodb 1.0.9 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo has the wrong version (1.6.0-dev) installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the mongo-php extension. The latest stable version of the `doctrine/mongodb` package doesn't support your installed version `1.5.0dev` of the mongodb driver. Downgrade it to the latest 1.4 version. Also it's better refer to beta packages instead of dev in your composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@beta",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@beta"
}
```

So your `minimum-stability` can remain `stable`.

Answer (score 1):

it because in your composer.json you have a line like this : "minimum-stability": "dev",
and you're trying to import maybe a beta version of MongoDBBundle

try with those lines in the require part:

```
"doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@dev",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev"
```

Comment: I updated my question. I put what I have in my composer.json file. I would also like to add that I am going by the symfony installation tutorial

Comment: try to add this line at the end of your file : "minimum-stability": "dev",

Comment: ok, in procoess. there is something there already called "minimum-stability": "stable"  . should I remove this ??

Comment: try to replace "stable" by "dev"

Comment: Replacing the minimum stability with dev is a very bad ide, as ist will update all dependencies to the latest unstable version.

Comment: I am getting this error now....  Cannot import resource "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/activebook/app/config/config.yml" from "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/activebook/app/config/config_dev.yml". (There is no extension able to load the configuration for "doctrine_mongodb"

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to enable the php_mongo.dll from php.ini file.

If it is not found in php.ini file the you have to add

extension=php_mongo.dll

at php ini file and then download php_mongo.dll from 
http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.5.5/windows
 and save it at php/ext/

then restart the apache
Now it will not give any error.